# How Core Data chooses the persistent store to save/fetch the data?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Let’s say I have a `managed object context` whose `persistent store coordinator` have two (or more) `persistent stores`.

Which persistent store will `Core Data` use to fetch or save `managed objects` when executing a fetch request, or saving the context?

Comment: There is a great way to find out about these things - make your persistent store of type XML. Then you can just open the XML file(s) and see all your saved objects in your favourite ASCII editor.

Comment: Well that’s a good idea to start hacking. I could add two XML persistent stores and see what is saved in which. But I’d like to have an authoritative answer if possible, with details on _why_ one persistent store has been selected over the other, is it possible to change the selected store, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have more than one configuration in the data model, and different configurations have different entities, a newly inserted object goes into whatever persistent store is associated with the object's entity. This is the purpose of the `configuration` option when you call `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`. You're telling the persistent store coordinator that the new persistent store uses a specific configuration. As a result, the persistent store only uses the entity types that the configuration contains.

If you have multiple persistent stores that can all save the same entities (they use the same configuration, or they have different configurations that overlap for some entities), then you have the option to tell the managed object context which persistent store to use. After inserting the object, but before saving changes, call `assignObject:toPersistentStore:` to tell it which one you want it to use. If you don't call that method, it's undefined which persistent store is used, but it's probably the last one that you added.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! About fetches, they are done from all persistent stores I presume?

Comment: Yes, any persistent store that the persistent store coordinator can reach.

Comment: What about delete? Is MO deleted for all persistent stores at once? Even if it is assigned to some specific one?

Comment: A managed object is only saved in one persistent store, so deleting it in "all" persistent stores doesn't make sense. It's deleted from whichever persistent store it was in.

Comment: What can happen if pesistent store is reassigned? E.g. I have in-memory persistent store which has been added last (so is used by default), so first MO is saved there. Then I assign it to the SQLite persistent store and save it there?

Comment: You cannot reassign the persistent store, it's a one-time operation. If you want to move data from one store to another, you have to create a new instance and copy the property values.